# Will changing the column names in SQL Server have an effect on my SSIS packages?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I was just wondering if I change column names on tables in SQL Server will they effect my SSIS packages.

Comment: [Click here to submit feedback about your question-asking experience.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258129)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it would, the source component would fail with a "Component (1) failed validation and returned validation status VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA".

Answer (score 1):

Sure will and they can be painful and time consuming to fix. You may need to go through steps all through the data flow not just the intial one or the final one (depending on whether you are changing the source or destination). Unions in the dataflow can be a particular pain point. If you want the change to reflect in a file you are creating, you may need to revisit the connection as well.